# Can one construct a "good" hash function using CRC32C as a base?

Tags: hash, intel, sse, crc32

Given that SSE 4.2 (Intel Core i7 & i5 parts) includes a CRC32 instruction, it seems reasonable to investigate whether one could build a faster general-purpose hash function. According to [this](http://home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/8.html) only 16 bits of a CRC32 are evenly distributed. So what other transformation would one apply to overcome that?

**Update**
How about this? Only 16 bits are suitable for a hash value. Fine. If your table is 65535 or less then great. If not, run the CRC value through the Nehalem POPCNT (population count) instruction to get the number of bits set. Then, use that as an index into an array of tables. This works if your table is south of 1mm entries. I'd bet that's cheaper/faster that the best-performing hash functions. Now that [GCC 4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html) has a CRC32 intrinsic it should be easy to test...if only I had the copious spare time to work on it.

David

Answer (score 17):

**Revisited**, August 2014
Prompted by *Arnaud Bouchez* in a recent comment, and in view of other answers and comments, I acknowledge that the original answer needs to be altered or for the least qualified.  I left the original as-is, at the end, for reference.

First, and maybe most important, a fair answer to the question depends on the *intended use of the hash code*:  What does one mean by "good" [hash function...]?  Where/how will the hash be used? (e.g. is it for hashing a relatively short input key?  Is it for indexing / lookup purposes, to produce message digests or yet other uses? How long is the desired hash code itself, all 32 bits [of CRC32 or derivatives thereof], more bits, fewer...  etc?
The OP questions calls for "*a **faster** **general-purpose** hash function*", so the focus is on SPEED (something less CPU intensive and/or something which can make use of parallel processing of various nature). We may note here that the computation time for the hash code itself is often only part of the problem in an application of hash (for example if the size of the hash code or its intrinsic characteristics result in many collisions which require extra cycles to be dealt with).  Also the requirement for "general purpose" leaves many questions as to the possible uses.

With this in mind, a short and better answer is, maybe:

**Yes**, the hardware implementations of CRC32C on newer Intel processors can be used to build faster hash codes; beware however that depending on the specific implementation of the hash and on its application the overall results may be sub-optimal because of the frequency of collisions, of the need to use longer codes.   Also, for sure, cryptographic uses of the hash should be carefully vetted because the CRC32 algorithm itself is very weak in this regard.

The original answer cited a article on Evaluating Hash functions by Bret Mulvey and as pointed in Mdlg's answer, **the conclusion of this article are erroneous in regards to CRC32** as the implementation of CRC32 it was based on was buggy/flawed.  Despite this major error in regards to CRC32, the article provides useful guidance as to the properties of hash algorithms in general.  The URL to this article is now defunct; I found it on [archive.today](http://archive.today/6rBZF#selection-251.11-251.21) but I don't know if the author has it at another location and also whether he updated it.

Other answers here cite **CityHash 1.0** as an example of a hash library that uses CRC32C. Apparently, this is used in the context of some longer (than 32 bits) hash codes but not for the CityHash32() function itself.  Also, the use of CRC32 by City Hash functions is relatively small, compared with all the shifting and shuffling and other operations that are performed to produce the hash code.  (This is not a critique of CityHash for which I have no hands-on experience.  I'll go on a limb, from a cursory review of the source code that  CityHash functions produce good, e.g. ell distributed codes,  but are not significantly faster than various other hash functions.)

Finally, you may also find insight on this issue in a [quasi duplicate question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953958/can-crc32-be-used-as-a-hash-function) .

---

Original answer and edit (April 2010)

*A priori*, **this sounds like a bad idea!**.

CRC32 was *not* designed for hashing purposes, and its distribution is likely to not be uniform, hence making it a relatively poor hash-code.  Furthermore, its "scrambling" power is relatively weak, making for a very poor one-way hash, as would be used in cryptographic applications.

*[BRB: I'm looking for online references to that effect...]*

Google's first [keywords = CRC32 distribution] hit seems to confirm this :
 [**Evaluating CRC32 for hash tables**](http://home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/8.html)

**Edit**: The page cited above, and indeed the [complete article](http://home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/) provides **a good basis of what to look for in Hash functions**.
Reading [quickly] this article, confirmed the blanket statement that *in general* CRC32 should not be used as a hash, however, and depending on the specific purpose of the hash, it may be possible to use, at least in part, a CRC32 as a hash code.

For example the lower (or higher, depending on implementation) 16 bits of the CRC32 code have a relatively even distribution, and, provided that one isn't concerned about the cryptographic properties of the hash code (i.e. for example the fact that similar keys produce very similar codes), it may be possible to build a hash code which uses, say, a concatenation of the lower [or higher] 16 bits for two CRC32 codes produced with the two halves (or whatever division) of the original key.
One would need to run tests to see if the efficiency of the built-in CRC32 instruction, relative to an alternative hash functions, would be such that the overhead of calling the instruction twice and splicing the code together etc. wouldn't result in an overall slower function.

Comment: MJV, thanks for your effort to provide what the Minutemen might have called "...a richer understanding of what's already understood." My apologies a posteriori for not having been more explicit.

Comment: A CRC is designed exactly for hashing purposes with the minimum possibility of collision.  It's fine for general purpose (not security related) hashing use.

Comment: @rsking. Not exactly. Minimizing the number of possible collisions is a _secondary_ goal for CRC design; the primary goal is to maximize its error detection performance _in the context of a particular expected distribution of the keys_  With purely random keys these two goals are completely compatible, however, CRCs are typically selected with a particular channel in mind, both in terms of its typical contents and it terms of its most common error patterns.  This was the case in particular for CRC32 and the 1975 paper by K Brayer and J Hammond make specific mention of this.  Furthermore ...

Comment: ... the fact that CRC32 is not evenly distribted can be asserted by various empiric tests such the one mentioned in the answer.
This poor [overall] disttibution is not a design flaw but rather a confirmation that the focus was on limiting collisions ["locally"] _for messages of similar lengths submitted to the same noisy channel_ rather than for arbitrary messages submitted to random noise.  Hence, a CRC is not necessarily well suited to be used as a generic purpose hash.

Comment: -1 Quoted article, used as reference, is using a wrong implementation of crc32 - see Mdlg answer below. So this article is not a "good basis of what to look for Hash functions". I would like to see this answer updated. From my own experiment, crc32 are very good candidate for a hash function.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez , thank you for nudging me in improving the answer.  BTW, I felt compelled to have this long edit, which may seem like I don't want to admit I was wrong. I -truly- wish my original answer was _completely_ wrong (so that the wiki would get fixed by merely deleting it or adding a few words at its top pointing to why it is wrong and where better answers are to be found, rather than this long discussion.)

Comment: @mjv Thanks for the update! Now we are talking. ;) AFAIK the OP explicitly asked for a hash function to be used in hash tables (read the "Update"): so you can make your answer shorter - no need to discuss other uses, like message digest. 32 bits of precision is enough for a hash table (unless your hash table will have 2^32 slots, i.e. using 32 GB of RAM in x64 - which is not plausible). So in this context, `crc32c` sounds like a winner as general-purpose hash function. This is now what your answer states! Great! :)

Comment: Link to archive.today is broken as well, there is a copy of article at [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20100916211701/http://home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/8.html)

Answer (score 15):

**The article referred to in other answers draws incorrect conclusions based on buggy crc32 code.** Google's ranking algorithm does not rank based on scientific accuracy yet.

Contrary to the referred article ["Evaluating CRC32 for hash tables"](http://home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/8.html) conclusions, **CRC32 and CRC32C are acceptable for hash table use**. The author's sample code has a bug in the crc32 table generation. Fixing the crc32 table, gives satifactory results using the same methodology. Also the speed of the CRC32 instruction, makes it the best choice in many contexts. Code using the CRC32 instruction is 16x faster at peak than an optimal software implementation. (Note that CRC32 is not exactly the same than CRC32C which the intel instruction implements.)

CRC32 is obviously not suitable for crypto use. (32 bit is a joke to brute force).

Comment: +1 It is worth mentioning that the quoted article wrongly implemented crc32! In practice, working on UTF-8 text, we found out that crc32 is the best compromise in terms of speed and collision (better e.g. than Kernighan & Ritchie, BobJenkins, FNV1a). And latest SSE4.2 CPUs do have an hardcoded crc32c intruction, which outperforms everything else in terms of performance. See http://blog.synopse.info/post/2014/05/25/New-crc32c%28%29-function-using-optimized-asm-and-SSE-4.2-instruction and http://www.delphitools.info/2014/08/25/string-hashing-shootout/comment-page-1/#comment-3423

Comment: not for crypto: not only can it be brute-forced easily, it can also be solved analytically.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.** [CityHash 1.0.1](http://code.google.com/p/cityhash/) includes some new "good hash functions" that use CRC32 instructions.

Answer (score 3):

For cryptographic purposes, CRC32 is a bad fundation because it is linear (over the vector space *GF(2)^32*) and that is hard to correct. It may work for non-cryptographic purposes.

However, recent Intel cores have the [AES-NI](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-advanced-encryption-standard-aes-instructions-set/) instructions, which basically perform 1/10th of an AES block encryption in two clock cycles. They are available on the most recent i5 and i7 processors (see the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) for some details). *This* looks like a good start for building a cryptographic hash function (and a hash function which is good for cryptography will also be good for about anything else).

Indeed, at least one of the [SHA-3 "round 2" candidates](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/sha-3/Round2/submissions_rnd2.html) (the [ECHO](http://crypto.rd.francetelecom.com/echo/) hash function) is built around the AES elements so that the AES-NI opcodes provide a very substantial performance boost. (Unfortunately, in the absence of AES-NI instruction, ECHO performance somewhat sucks.)

Answer (score 2):

Just so long as you're not after crypto hash it just might work.