# how to make my own hash code from string?

Tags: c, string, encryption, hashcode

I am beginner in cryptography, but I want to make a simple hash code function in C. My concept is, I have a string `"helloiam"` and a integer `433`. Can I convert the string in to encrypted format like `"233ASDJJ6688FGSS"` something like that?
I don't know unsigned integer or 128 bit integer format. Any simple code to convert string using a integer to form a hash code. I generate that unique integer for every string. But I want to use this integer on the string to form a hash code like `"233ASDJJ6688FGSS"`.
How can I make this?
Any sample code in C?
I don't want to make complex algorithms for making hash code. I am try to make my own.

Comment: Why do you need an additional integer in hashing? Maybe you want to encrypt it instead of making a hash?

Answer (score 1):

Try CRC32: [Can CRC32 be used as a hash function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953958/can-crc32-be-used-as-a-hash-function)

Few other options at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Answer (score 1):

Hash function **can only give you more or less long integer values**, the format with character is a formatting of the integer, like converting it to a string or formatting it with printf

Some well known integer formatting available are :

- binary (base 2)
- octal (base 8)
- decimal ( base 10 )
- hexadecimal ( base 16)
- base64
  ...

you can of course roll your own by choosing a base for your number, meaning how many characters are in your figures list to write your number.
You can then write a correspondence table to match the number with the correct character.